# Haskell, splitting a list into specified chunks causing infinite loop

Tags: string, haskell, split, char, chunks

How can I stop Haskell from infinity performing the function?

```
splitList i ""  = []
splitList i str = let (x, y) = splitAt i str
                  in x : splitList i x
```

Comment: I think you missed the **base case** of the function.

Comment: It's because it's a recursive function right? I just need to know how to make it stop once the string has been grouped into chunks

Comment: Compile with warnings, it will show you your error (see the unused variable).

Comment: @MikeNoelHiggs Yes, it is. Anyway, you should give us an example input and the expected output.

Comment: IOW `x` should be `y`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this ^

Comment: expected input is `splitList 2 "HelloWorld"'`
expect output is `[He, ll, oW, or, ld]`
however it will just group He infinity.

Comment: @MikeNoelHiggs: where do you use `y` in the `in ...` part?

Comment: y is the string, x is the number to group by

Comment: @MikeNoelHiggs: but you write `splitList i x`.

Comment: how would you write it?

Answer (score 4):

Try to step through the implementation in GHCi:

```
Prelude> i = 2
Prelude> str = "HelloWorld"
Prelude> let (x, y) = splitAt i str
Prelude> x
"He"
Prelude> y
"lloWorld"
```

In the next pass, `splitList` calls itself recursively with `i` and `x`, where `x` is `"He"`:

```
Prelude> str = x
Prelude> let (x, y) = splitAt i str
Prelude> x
"He"
Prelude> y
""
```

In the third pass, `splitList` again calls itself recursively with `i` and `x`. Notice that `x` hasn't changed between the first and the second call. Do you see the infinite recursion now?

Comment: Yes, would you be able to fix this for me? I'm just getting really confused where I should use the tail or how to update x after a pass

Comment: @MikeNoelHiggs From your recent history of questions, it looks like you're learning Haskell. That's great! You learn best by doing exercises yourself, so while I'm happy to help making things clearer, and to teach you how to solve problems yourself, I don't think you'll learn anything if I just give you the solution. You are, however, welcome to ask another question if you're stuck on other parts of the problem.

Comment: In that case can you direct me to a slimier question? from what I understand the tail (y) isn't being used as it's just calling x (head) over and over, however I don't know how to step over to the tail after x has been grouped :/

Comment: @MikeNoelHiggs: `y` is *not* the tail. Note that we pattern match with a tuple (`(x, y)`), not a list cons `(x : y)`.

Comment: @MikeNoelHiggs Indeed, `y` isn't being used. Why not? I assume that you wrote the `splitList` code, so you ought to be in a better position to answer why you chose to do that than I am.

Comment: solved 

`splitList i ""  = []
splitList i str = let (x, y) = splitAt i str
                       in x : splitList i y`

Basically I was chopping the list at x after each recursion rather than y (being the rest of the string) is this correct?